# liberal xml parser for c# or java

Tags: c#, java

I am looking for a liberal xml parser, one for java and one for C#, that can "properly" parse

1. unquoted attribute values
2. non-conjugated attribute

like:

```
<Person id=candy female single phone=555.666.7777 />
```

rather than

```
<Person id='candy' female='true' single='true' phone='555.666.7777'/>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you absolutely have to fix this on the parsing/reading side? Are you able to fix the problem from the generating side instead?

Comment: @Juliet, a very good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

jericho html parser in java can handle non-validating xml. nekohtml and jtidy are also available. there may be some methods to output back a validating doc.

in c#, you might be able to use Tidy.Net since the markup resembles loose html, or .NET's native HTMLDocumentClass

Comment: jericho and other HTML parsers seem to work only for HTML but not for general XML.